# Cannot find module 'common-tags' while running npm install -g @angular/cli on Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a new project in Visual Studio Code but The following error: Cannot find module 'common-tags' shows up when I run the command npm install -g @angular/cli in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is basically due to version. The following worked for me:

`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` **OR/AND** `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`

```
npm cache clean --force 
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

Comment: Can you explain why you used cache clean? Cache since npm5 is self healing and can be verified by doing `npm cache verify`.